# How to get the correct checkbox result from database MySQL?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have 3 table here.

1)Hotel

```
-----------------
|Hotel_ID | Name     |
-----------------
|    1    |Shangrila |
----------------------
|    2    |GoldHill  |
----------------------
|    3    |BayBeach  |
----------------------
```

2)Feature

```
----------------------
|Feature_ID| Feature |
----------------------
|     1    |  Goft   |
----------------------
|     2    |Internet |
----------------------
```

3)Brdige_Hotel_Feature

```
------------------------
|Hotel_ID | Feature_ID |
------------------------
|    1    |      1     |
------------------------
|    1    |      2     |
-----------------------
|     2   |      1     |
-----------------------
```

It mean each hotel might have more than 1 feature.

My idea is like this , let say, if i want get the result from table 3 Bridge_Hotel_Feature.
If the Feature_ID = 1 , i get
Hotel 1 and 2. 
**If the Feature_ID = 1 , 2. I just want to get 
Hotel 1. 
But i always get the both Hotel_ID 1 and 2. ** 
Please help me the solution to get only the feature match with the Hotel_ID.

Below is the code i try.

```
SELECT h.Name , h.Hotel_ID, f.feature
FROM Hotel h, Bridge1_Hotel_Features b, Features f
where 0=0
AND b.Feature_ID = f.Feature_ID 
AND b.Hotel_ID = r.Hotel_ID

<cfif #FORM.Feature_ID# IS NOT "">
    AND f.Feature_ID IN (#FORM.Feature_ID#)
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If Feature_ID = 1 ,2 , the result must
>   **only** get Hotel_ID = 1

Because only Hotel_ID = 1 has both features, correct? Assuming `#FORM.Feature_ID#` does not contain duplicates, use a HAVING clause to dynamically identify hotels with all of the requested features.

```
SELECT Hotel_ID, COUNT(Feature_ID) AS FeatureCount
FROM   Bridge_Hotel_Feature
<!--- find matching features --->
WHERE  Feature_ID IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Feature_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> )
GROUP BY Hotel_ID
<!--- having ALL of the requested features --->
HAVING COUNT(Feature_ID) = <cfqueryparam value="#listLen(FORM.Feature_ID)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
```

You could then join to it as a derived table or possibly a subquery. The sql needs optimization, but conceptually something like

```
SELECT h.Hotel_ID, h.Name, f.Feature
FROM   Hotel h
      INNER JOIN Bridge_Hotel_Feature b ON b.Hotel_ID = h.Hotel_ID
      INNER JOIN Features f ON b.Feature_ID = f.Feature_ID
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT Hotel_ID, COUNT(Feature_ID) AS FeatureCount
        FROM   Bridge_Hotel_Feature
        <!--- find matching features --->
        WHERE  Feature_ID IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Feature_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> )
        GROUP BY Hotel_ID
        <!--- having ALL of the requested features --->
        HAVING COUNT(Feature_ID) = <cfqueryparam value="#listLen(FORM.Feature_ID)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    ) ck ON ck.Hotel_ID = h.Hotel_Id
```

Comment: Thank you first, I have try the first code u given me.
But i fail to get any result even just tick 1 box. 
By The Way, can i know what the use for COUNT(Feature_ID) AS FeatureCount? because it no connect the following code.

Comment: @Raywin - Using `FORM.Feature_ID = "1,2"` the 1st query returns Hotel_ID 1. Can you post your sql? The COUNT(Feature_ID) is used to find only records that have *all* of the selected features.

Comment: Leigh, thank , if just follow your first code exactly, i can get the answer, when i try just add on restaurant r then i could not get any answer. 

2nd code u show me, i keep get error with 'HAVING COUNT(Feature_ID) = 2 ) ck ON ck.Restaurant_ID = r.Restaurant_I'

Comment: SELECT b.Restaurant_ID, COUNT(b.Feature_ID) AS FeatureCount, r.Name, f.Feature
  FROM   Bridge1_Restaurant_Features b, Restaurants r, Features f
  <!--- find matching features --->
  WHERE  b.Feature_ID IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.Feature_ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="true"> )
  GROUP BY r.Restaurant_ID
  <!--- having ALL of the requested features --->
  HAVING COUNT(b.Feature_ID) = <cfqueryparam value="#listLen(FORM.Feature_ID)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">

Comment: @Raywin - Hm... actually I think I see a flaw in my logic. Let me fix that first.

Comment: Thank for patient for helping me ^^

Comment: @Raywin - I updated the second example based on original table names. It should work with MySQL. Can you try it again now?

Comment: Leigh ! Really appreciate for your help ! The code is perfect ! I'd be glad of you help !

Comment: @Leigh, sorry, i have create another post is continue with this question, would you might take a look ? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159337/inner-join-with-if-statement-please-help-me-to-group-them-up

Comment: @da_didi - Thanks for fixing the table names. I initially thought the name was literally "Brdige_..." .. and it was bugging me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change sql to:

```
SELECT h.Name , h.Hotel_ID, f.feature
FROM Hotel h, Bridge1_Hotel_Features b, Features f
where b.Feature_ID = f.Feature_ID 
      AND b.Hotel_ID = h.Hotel_ID

<cfif #FORM.Feature_ID# IS NOT "">
    AND b.Feature_ID IN (#FORM.Feature_ID#)
</cfif>
```

Essentially, the optional part of where clause should be restricting the feature_id in the Bridge_Hotel_Features table.

Comment: You don't need # # around variable names in your CFIF statement.  And you REALLY should use cfqueryparam on the form variable

Comment: Thank you everyone, i change to  
AND b.Feature_ID IN (#FORM.Feature_ID#).

But the result i still get both.
If Feature_ID = 1 ,2 , the result must only get Hotel_ID = 1 .

Comment: In that case, expand out the form.feature_id variable:

Comment: Thank duncan, your advise is important! avoid other to modify my database?

Comment: @Raywin - Yes, @duncan 's advice will help protect you against sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use EXIST to solve this problem.

```
SELECT h.Name , h.Hotel_ID, f.feature
FROM Hotel h, Bridge_Hotel_Feature b, Feature f
where b.Feature_ID = f.Feature_ID 
      AND b.Hotel_ID = h.Hotel_ID
AND EXISTS (SELECT feature_id FROM bridge_hotel_feature WHERE feature_id = 1 AND bridge_hotel_feature.hotel_ID = h.hotel_ID)
AND EXISTS (SELECT feature_id FROM bridge_hotel_feature WHERE feature_id = 2 AND bridge_hotel_feature.hotel_ID = h.hotel_ID)
```

**EDIT:**  The above is an example of what your query needs to look like. To make it dynamic you will add a loop.

I don't have coldfusion experience myself so I can't tell you verbatim what to do with that code.

But what you need to do is wrap the following section of code in a loop and append this to your query string for each checkbox and replace the feature_id in the where clause with the feature_id of each checkbox.
`AND EXISTS (SELECT feature_id FROM bridge_hotel_feature WHERE feature_id = 1 AND bridge_hotel_feature.hotel_ID = h.hotel_ID)`

I hope this makes it clearer for you.

Comment: I try his code, but if my checkbox tick more than 1 box , it get error.

Comment: What is the error message? Also, are features dynamic? ie Will there be more than 2 features

Comment: Erm..Because the question is just a simple example, but code have a checkbox, and might tick more than 1 box. Sorry , if just follow the code, there is no error and get the result, sorry for mistake

Comment: I edited my post.  Hopefully it makes it a little clearer as to what you need to do.  The SQL produces the correct results, I made a mock table and tested it, I just don't know the coldfusion.

Comment: Yup, Jrod your code is correct , thank you! Just my case have to use another logic, appreciate for your helping , i get some idea here.